# How do I share a rally dashboard with a single team

Tags: rally

I've created a couple of dashboards in my rally environment and since I cannot make them project viewable I would like to share the dashboard without sharing it with the entire workspace.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, shared pages in Rally get shared with everyone and cannot be set to be visible at the project level.  You will need to share with the desired users which apps and settings (or code if it is a custom HTML app) you are using in order for them to be able to re-create these themselves.

You could always post this as an idea at https://ideas.rallydev.com to get visibility for the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: There are a couple of Ideas on the site that you can up vote for this: https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D1754 and https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D1671